# WireGuard tunnel, can my ISP know I'm using tor?

Tags: vpn, tunnel

I plan deploy a setup similar to the following:

[image: network map]

My Tails PC and my custom DNS are on different subnets, all of my Internet traffic is routed through a WireGuard tunnel ending on a cloud VM (this could be Mullvad as well). The tunnel starts from a router in between my subnets and my ISP box.

My question is this : can my ISP know that I'm using Tor if they are sniffing my traffic or do they just see WireGuard things? And can my cloud provider see my Tor traffic (I think they can)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can my cloud provider see my Tor traffic (I think they can)?

They can see that you're using Tor, but not what you're doing on Tor.

> can my ISP know that I'm using Tor if they are sniffing my traffic or do they just see WireGuard things?

There isn't a yes/no answer for this. Typically no they wouldn't know that you're using Tor since they only see encrypted Wireguard traffic between your router and the cloud VPS. But your ISP could share information with the cloud VPS provider to link where the traffic is going after it leaves your VPS (this is common with VPN providers, but I'm not sure about cloud VPS providers). Or if they were specifically targeting you, they could maybe guess if your Wireguard traffic contained Tor traffic based on size and timing information.

So they probably wouldn't know, but you couldn't rule it out entirely.

Comment: This confirms my thoughts, thanks for the additional information!